# How do I group a sliding window in the j argument by ID?

Tags: r, data.table

This is an example of my data.table (called 'sub'):

```
 time         fly         mm genotype Genotype
 1:    1 test 0.68000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 2:    2 test 1.53394915  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 3:    3 test 1.40431478  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 4:    4 test 0.29154759  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 5:    5 test 0.67416615  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 6:    6 test 0.09848858  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 7:    7 test 2.46099573  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 8:    8 test 1.71143215  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
 9:    9 test 3.75767215  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
10:   10 test 5.99067609  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
11:   11 test 5.48714862  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
12:   12 test 0.00000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
13:   13 test 0.32015621  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
14:   14 test 0.75960516  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
15:   15 test 0.31953091  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
16:   16 test 0.67007462  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
17:   17 test 1.55467038  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
18:   18 test 1.13564959  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
19:   19 test 0.39051248  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
20:   20 test 1.31061054  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
21:   21 test 2.57007782  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
22:   22 test 1.78339564  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
23:   23 test 1.70484603  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
24:   24 test 0.63198101  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
25:   25 test 0.00000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
26:   26 real 1.74183811  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
27:   27 real 1.01000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
28:   28 real 0.85052925  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
29:   29 real 0.50000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
30:   30 real 0.56885851  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
31:   31 real 0.25000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
32:   32 real 0.46270941  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
33:   33 real 0.71000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
34:   34 real 0.30000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
35:   35 real 0.29410882  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
36:   36 real 0.65122961  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
37:   37 real 0.56435804  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
38:   38 real 1.37277092  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
39:   39 real 5.59322805  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
40:   40 real 3.15634282  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
41:   41 real 4.09078232  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
42:   42 real 2.02022276  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
43:   43 real 1.32196823  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
44:   44 real 1.98909527  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
45:   45 real 2.45985772  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
46:   46 real 3.61203544  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
47:   47 real 7.97250902  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
48:   48 real 3.05949342  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
49:   49 real 2.41754007  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
50:   50 real 1.27882759  ctrl1_f   loxP_f
```

My goal is to compare successive entries in the 'mm' column and check where a 0 is followed by a non-0, e.g. in row 12 in the code above, and again in row 25. The result should be saved in a new column.

When I do this, it works:

```
sub[, initiate := lapply(1:(nrow(.SD) - 1), function(x) mm[x] == 0 && mm[x + 1] != 0)]
```

And results in the following data.table:

```
    time  fly         mm genotype Genotype initiate
 1:    1 test 0.68000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 2:    2 test 1.53394915  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 3:    3 test 1.40431478  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 4:    4 test 0.29154759  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 5:    5 test 0.67416615  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 6:    6 test 0.09848858  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 7:    7 test 2.46099573  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 8:    8 test 1.71143215  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
 9:    9 test 3.75767215  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
10:   10 test 5.99067609  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
11:   11 test 5.48714862  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
12:   12 test 0.00000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f     TRUE
13:   13 test 0.32015621  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
14:   14 test 0.75960516  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
15:   15 test 0.31953091  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
16:   16 test 0.67007462  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
17:   17 test 1.55467038  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
18:   18 test 1.13564959  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
19:   19 test 0.39051248  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
20:   20 test 1.31061054  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
21:   21 test 2.57007782  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
22:   22 test 1.78339564  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
23:   23 test 1.70484603  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
24:   24 test 0.63198101  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
25:   25 test 0.00000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f     TRUE
26:   26 real 1.74183811  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
27:   27 real 1.01000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
28:   28 real 0.85052925  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
29:   29 real 0.50000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
30:   30 real 0.56885851  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
31:   31 real 0.25000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
32:   32 real 0.46270941  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
33:   33 real 0.71000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
34:   34 real 0.30000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
35:   35 real 0.29410882  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
36:   36 real 0.65122961  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
37:   37 real 0.56435804  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
38:   38 real 1.37277092  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
39:   39 real 5.59322805  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
40:   40 real 3.15634282  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
41:   41 real 4.09078232  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
42:   42 real 2.02022276  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
43:   43 real 1.32196823  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
44:   44 real 1.98909527  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
45:   45 real 2.45985772  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
46:   46 real 3.61203544  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
47:   47 real 7.97250902  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
48:   48 real 3.05949342  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
49:   49 real 2.41754007  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
50:   50 real 1.27882759  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE
```

This way, I correctly identify rows 12 and 25 as 'initiations', i.e. as rows where a 0 is followed by a non-0.

The problem I haven't been able to solve is: I want to do the same thing grouped by the 'fly' column, i.e. for 'test' and 'real' entries separately. When I do this, it doesn't give me the right answer:

```
sub[, initiate2 := lapply(1:(nrow(.SD) - 1), function(x) mm[x] == 0 && mm[x + 1] != 0), by = fly]

sub

    time  fly         mm genotype Genotype initiate initiate2
 1:    1 test 0.68000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 2:    2 test 1.53394915  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 3:    3 test 1.40431478  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 4:    4 test 0.29154759  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 5:    5 test 0.67416615  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 6:    6 test 0.09848858  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 7:    7 test 2.46099573  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 8:    8 test 1.71143215  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
 9:    9 test 3.75767215  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
10:   10 test 5.99067609  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
11:   11 test 5.48714862  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
12:   12 test 0.00000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f     TRUE     FALSE
13:   13 test 0.32015621  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
14:   14 test 0.75960516  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
15:   15 test 0.31953091  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
16:   16 test 0.67007462  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
17:   17 test 1.55467038  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
18:   18 test 1.13564959  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
19:   19 test 0.39051248  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
20:   20 test 1.31061054  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
21:   21 test 2.57007782  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
22:   22 test 1.78339564  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
23:   23 test 1.70484603  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
24:   24 test 0.63198101  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
25:   25 test 0.00000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f     TRUE     FALSE
26:   26 real 1.74183811  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
27:   27 real 1.01000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
28:   28 real 0.85052925  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
29:   29 real 0.50000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
30:   30 real 0.56885851  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
31:   31 real 0.25000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
32:   32 real 0.46270941  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
33:   33 real 0.71000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
34:   34 real 0.30000000  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
35:   35 real 0.29410882  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
36:   36 real 0.65122961  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
37:   37 real 0.56435804  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
38:   38 real 1.37277092  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
39:   39 real 5.59322805  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
40:   40 real 3.15634282  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
41:   41 real 4.09078232  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
42:   42 real 2.02022276  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
43:   43 real 1.32196823  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
44:   44 real 1.98909527  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
45:   45 real 2.45985772  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
46:   46 real 3.61203544  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
47:   47 real 7.97250902  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
48:   48 real 3.05949342  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
49:   49 real 2.41754007  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
50:   50 real 1.27882759  ctrl1_f   loxP_f    FALSE     FALSE
```

initiate2 gives me FALSE for both row 12 and 25, although it should give me TRUE for row 12 and FALSE for row 25. Why does this happen and how can I solve it? I'm new to data.table, so there might be something obvious I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `rle`, replace the `values` applying your condition "0 is followed by a non-0", i.e. `values == 0 & lengths == 1` and then call `inverse.rle`

```
DT[, initiate := {
  r <- rle(mm)
  r$values <- r$values == 0 & r$lengths == 1
  inverse.rle(r)
}, by = id][]
#    mm id initiate
# 1:  0  a     TRUE
# 2:  1  a    FALSE
# 3:  1  a    FALSE
# 4:  2  a    FALSE
# 5:  0  a     TRUE
# 6:  2  a    FALSE
# 7:  2  a    FALSE
# 8:  1  a    FALSE
# 9:  1  a    FALSE
#10:  0  a     TRUE
#11:  0  b    FALSE
#12:  0  b    FALSE
#13:  2  b    FALSE
#14:  1  b    FALSE
#15:  2  b    FALSE
#16:  1  b    FALSE
#17:  2  b    FALSE
#18:  2  b    FALSE
#19:  1  b    FALSE
#20:  2  b    FALSE
```

**data**

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(mm = sample(0:2, 20, TRUE),
                 id = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10))
DT
#    mm id
# 1:  0  a
# 2:  1  a
# 3:  1  a
# 4:  2  a
# 5:  0  a
# 6:  2  a
# 7:  2  a
# 8:  1  a
# 9:  1  a
#10:  0  a
#11:  0  b
#12:  0  b
#13:  2  b
#14:  1  b
#15:  2  b
#16:  1  b
#17:  2  b
#18:  2  b
#19:  1  b
#20:  2  b
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Markus, I wasn't aware of rle's existence - a very handy function indeed. This solved my issue.